# Personal view for another user

Tags: 2007, list-view

How can I create a personal view for another user in MOSS 2007? I am a SharePoint site collection admin.

Comment: Do you need a solution via the web UI (AFAIK, it is not possible), or a code sample in C# / PowerShell would help either? The solution (http://www.stefan-walter.net/swpersonalviews/) suggested in this thread (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/managing-personal-views-of-other-users) seems to work only with SP 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Personal views would be created by the user himself, if you have a column in the list (hidden) for all items called: ViewedBy of type People Picker, then you would populate this column with the user's name for all items he would want to see, and then create a view to items where ViewedBy == TheUser. That would not be the best solution, but if you're not intending of using code as suggested by @pholpar, then this would be a way to go.